# using UIDevice uniqueIdentifier in iOS5 for Notifications

Tags: ios, ios5, apple-push-notifications

UIDevice uniqueIdentifier is already deprecated in iOS5, can I still use this? I'm using it for Remote Notification by following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2), and the current alternative for uniqueIdentifier does not satisfy what I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The device ID is deprecated for a reason. You should not associate user-information with a particular device, because the device could be sold or replaced by the user and you may leak information to other parties.

If you need a unique value, generate a GUID the first time your application is launched. Save this to `NSUserDefaults` so it is backed up during a sync, and use this GUID in place of the device id.

Comment: how about using device token as the primary key in a table? is device token unique to a device?

Comment: You should not associate user information with any kind of device id or token. What if your user upgrades to a new phone? They won't get notifications, and if somebody else uses their old phone, they will get notifications that aren't meant for them. Follow Apple's advice and generate your own GUID.